# Using Coalesce For Comma Delimited List

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

`Coalesce will return the first non-null value among its arguments` documentation says. I can also use  it like below:

```
DECLARE @ColumnValue VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @ColumnValue = COALESCE(@ColumnValue+',','') + ColumnValue
FROM dbo.TableA
SELECT @ColumnValue
```

According to my understanding, there should be a `,` at the very front of the output list since at the very beginning there will at least be a comma passed as an argument. Also, if I put some value in the second argument. It appears at the very front instead of the `,` as I expected.

If someone can please explain the code to me. I will be very grateful.

Comment: You better explain clearly what are you trying to achieve and illustrate it with sample data

Comment: If @ColmnValue is null and you are adding ',' to that, then the result is still going to be NULL, in which case you will get the next value in coalesce being ''

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that SQL string concatenation behaves so differently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your understanding is not correct.

Focus  on the expression:

```
SELECT @ColumnValue = COALESCE(@ColumnValue+',','') + ColumnValue
-------------------------------^XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The first argument to `COALESCE()` is `@ColumnValue+','`.  This is NULL initially, so it gets replaced by `''`.  Then comes `ColumnValue` as the first element in the list.

You are likely thinking of:

```
SELECT @ColumnValue = COALESCE(@ColumnValue, '') + ',' + ColumnValue
```

Comment: Thank you sir for taking the trouble to answer my question. Very insightful answer.

Answer (score 6):

You are confused. Since at first `@ColumnValue` is `NULL`, then the result of `@ColumnValue + ','` is also `NULL`, so the result of `COALESCE(@ColumnValue+',','')` is `''`. This is easily tested with:

```
DECLARE @ColumnValue VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT COALESCE(@ColumnValue+',','')
```